# xml and json both giving garbage for language other then english

Tags: iphone, xml, json, parsing

here is a sample of my xml file

```
<TheamName>
    <item1>Green</item1>
    <item2>Blue</item2>
</TheamName>

<FontName>
    <item1>دعاء</item1>
    <item2>دعاء</item2>
    <item3>دعاء</item3>
    <item4>دعاء</item4>
</FontName>
```

but when i tried to parse this having this response

```
{
    item1 = Green;
    item2 = Blue;
},
    {
    item1 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
    item2 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
    item3 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
    item4 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
}
```

tried to convert it on json and then tried to have response but have no success it gives the same result for that also.

please show me how to get the original different language string back?

Thakas in advance for the help!

**EDIT**

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSString *theXML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[arrXmlData mutableBytes] length:[arrXmlData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

arrSession = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *nodesLibRateEstimate = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Headings" error:nil];
for (CXMLElement *node in nodesLibRateEstimate) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for(int counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
        if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"app_name"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"app_name"];
        }else if([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"action_settings"]){
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"action_settings"];
        }
    }
    [arrSession addObject:dictData];
}

NSArray *nodesLibOriginatingServiceCenter = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//TheamName" error:nil];
for (CXMLElement *node in nodesLibOriginatingServiceCenter) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for(int counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
        if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"item1"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"item1"];
        } else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"item2"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"item2"];
        }
    }
    [arrSession addObject:dictData];
}

NSArray *nodesLibOriginatingServiceCenter2 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//FontName" error:nil];
for (CXMLElement *node in nodesLibOriginatingServiceCenter2) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for(int counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
        if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"item1"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"item1"];
        } else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"item2"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"item2"];
        } else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"item3"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"item3"];
        } else if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"item4"]) {
            NSString *strValue;
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]isEqualToString:@""] || [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]==nil) {
                strValue=@"";
            }else{
                strValue=[self trimString:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
            [dictData setObject:strValue forKey:@"item4"];
        }
    }
    [arrSession addObject:dictData];
}

NSLog(@"The arrSession is :%@",arrSession);

[connection release];
[arrXmlData release];
}
```

Comment: This response seems good as these are the unicode of the characters

Comment: okay but how can i convert back to the response i need?

Comment: show us some code where you are generating the response. I'm curious how you are getting the out put

Comment: take a look at my EDIT portion at the end of parsing means in connectiondidfinish method i write the code for response.

Answer (score 1):

Your response is right

Instead of printing it in array try to print it individually.

e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[arrSession objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"item1"]);
```

Assuming that your

```
{
    item1 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
    item2 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
    item3 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
    item4 = "\U062f\U0639\U0627\U0621";
}
```

is at index `1` in `arrSession`